# Is there any difference using {} pair or () pair when define function-like macro in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For example:

```
#define FOO(x)     (printf(x))
```

and

```
#define FOO(x)     {printf(x)}
```

It seems that both are viable for preprocessing, but which is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're treating the macro as an expression, use the `()` form.

If you're treating it as a command (and *never* as an expression) then use the `{}` form. Or rather, use the `do{}while(0)` form as that has fewer substitution hazards when used near keywords like `if`:

```
#define FOO(x) do {    \
    printf(x);         \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses `()` are used to enforce correct evaluation regardless of operator precedence, so that you hopefully won't get any nasty side effects when the macro is expanded.

Braces `{}` are used to make the macro a C block statement, although the canonical way to do this is:

```
#define FOO(x) \
  do { \
    ... stuff ... \
  } while (0)
```

Note that gcc provides an extension to the C language which makes it possible to return a value from a block - the last expression evaluated will be the value returned if the block is used as part of an expression.

Comment: Please note evaluation order and precedence are two different things.

Comment: you mean I can write something like this "if (FOO(var)) {...}" by using your FOO macro defined above?

Comment: @solotim: in gcc yes, but not in compilers which do not have this gcc extension. It's probably best to avoid gcc-specific extensions though, and even better to use inline functions rather than macros wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you will ever need `FOO(x)` inside an expression, then you cannot use the `{}` form.  For example:

```
result = FOO(some_variable);
```

or

```
if (FOO(some_variable))
```

Comment: Unless you're using gcc, which allows a block to return a value when used in an expression.

Comment: @Paul R: Fair enough, I didn't know that.  What about `if (FOO(some_variable))`?

Comment: yes - same deal - gcc lets you do this. Probably best avoided though - use inline functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using parens in a macro is to control precedence when the macro is expanded. Consider:

```
#define X( a, b ) a * b
```

if the macro is used like this

```
X( 1 + 2, 3 )
```

we would presumably like the answer to be 9, but what we get on expansion is:

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

giving us 7. To avoid this kind of thing, we should have written the macro as:

```
#define X( a, b ) ((a) * (b))
```

If precedence is not an issue, brackets either type are not absolutely required, though braces may be needed depending on the ,macros semantics - if for example you want to create a  local variable,